# Code not decoding message sent through sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, encoding, byte, decoding

I'm creating a chat room in python using the socket module. When ever I send a message, I put in a line of code to decode it, but it just doesn't decode it.

example with the message: hi

code:

```py
recvmessage = connection.recv(9999)
recvmessage.decode('utf8')
print(recvmessage)
```

result:

```py
b'hi'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `.decode("utf-8")` doesn't update the variable in-place. So you'd either have to write:

```py
recvmessage = recvmessage.decode("utf-8")
```

or directly:

```py
print(recvmessage.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: thanks, its very confusing working with sockets in python